# How to get mysql random integer range?

Tags: mysql, random

I am trying to generate a random integer for each row I select between 1 and 60 as timer.

```
SELECT downloads.date, products.*, (FLOOR(1 + RAND() * 60)) AS timer
```

I have searched and keep coming up to this FLOOR function as how to select a random integer in a range. This is giving me a 1 for every row.
What am I missing?

I am on mysql   5.0.75

Heres the rest of the query I belive it might be a nesting issue

```
SELECT *
FROM (
 SELECT downloads.date, products.*, FLOOR(1 + (RAND() * 60)) AS randomtimer, 
 (
 SELECT COUNT( * )
 FROM distros
 WHERE distros.product_id = products.product_id
 ) AS distro_count,

 (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM downloads WHERE downloads.product_id = products.product_id) AS true_downloads

 FROM downloads
 INNER JOIN products ON downloads.product_id = downloads.product_id
) AS count_table
WHERE count_table.distro_count > 0
AND count_table.active = 1
ORDER BY count_table.randomtimer , count_table.date DESC LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 123, accepted):

This is working for me. Your mysql version maybe?

```
SELECT id, (FLOOR( 1 + RAND( ) *60 )) AS timer
FROM users
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: But this query repeats values

Answer (score 4):

Old question, but always actual problem.

Here a way to create a MySQL function `random_integer()` [based on manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand) :

```
CREATE FUNCTION random_integer(value_minimum INT, value_maximum INT)
RETURNS INT
COMMENT 'Gets a random integer between value_minimum and value_maximum, bounds included'
RETURN FLOOR(value_minimum + RAND() * (value_maximum - value_minimum + 1));
```

```
SELECT ALL random_integer(1, 60) AS timer;
```

Answer (score 3):

The output of the `RAND` function will always be a value between **0** and **1**.

Try this:

```
SELECT downloads.date, products.*, (CAST(RAND() * 60 AS UNSIGNED) + 1) AS timer
```

Comment: you can use floor instead of casting to int, casting uses round.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the number multiplied by the number of records in the table.

```
SELECT id,
(FLOOR( (SELECT MIN(id) FROM your_table ) + RAND( ) * 1000000 ) ) AS timer
FROM your_table
LIMIT 0 , 30
```