# MySQL get a random value between two values

Tags: php, mysql

I have two columns in a row: `min_value`, `max_value`. Is there a way to do a select like:

```
SELECT RAND(`min_v`, `max_v`) `foo` [..]
```

I do realize that `RAND` does a different thing; the closest I came up (with help) is `(RAND() * (max-min))+min`, though it will produce a float number, which I'd need then to ROUND() and this is just completely wrong.

Unless anyone can suggest an alternative (which would be very useful), I will go PHP way.

Comment: Please describe the task. Maybe you don't need rand() at all.

Comment: I need to get a random value between two values in columns `min_v` and `max_v` respectively.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Actually, `ROUND((RAND() * (max-min))+min)` is the best way in MySQL to do what you'd like. It is also the best way in ActionScript, JavaScript, and Python. Honestly, I prefer it to the PHP way because it is more convenient.

Because I don't know how many rows you'll be returning, I can't advise you whether it is better to use PHP or MySQL for this, but if you're dealing with a large number of values you probably are better off using MySQL.

### Addendum

---

So, there was a question as to whether this is better in PHP or MySQL. Instead of getting into a debate on principles, I ran the following:

```
<pre><?php

$c = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');

if(!$c) die('!');
echo mysql_select_db('test', $c)?'Connection':'Failure';
echo PHP_EOL;

echo ':::::::::::::::::::::::::BEGINNING MYSQL RAND::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::'.PHP_EOL;
$start = microtime(1);
for( $i = 0; $i < 100000; $i++ )
{
    $r = mysql_query( 'SELECT ROUND(RAND() * (200-10) + 10) FROM dual' );
    $r = mysql_fetch_array( $r );
}
$end = microtime(1);

echo  ($end - $start) . " for MySQL select".PHP_EOL;

echo ':::::::::::::::::::::::::BEGINNING PHP RAND::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::' .PHP_EOL;
$start = microtime(1);
for( $i = 0; $i < 100000; $i++ )
{
    $r = mysql_query( 'SELECT 200 AS two, 10 AS tem FROM dual' );
    $r = mysql_fetch_array( $r );
    $r[2]= rand($r[0], $r[1]);
}
$end = microtime(1);

echo  ($end - $start) . " for PHP select".PHP_EOL;
```

MySQL is faster by about 2-3%.

If you use this, however (note, more columns return by MySQL):

```
<pre><?php

$c = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');

if(!$c) die('!');
echo mysql_select_db('test', $c)?'Connection':'Failure';
echo PHP_EOL;

echo ':::::::::::::::::::::::::BEGINNING MYSQL RAND::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::'.PHP_EOL;
$start = microtime(1);
for( $i = 0; $i < 100000; $i++ )
{
    $r = mysql_query( 'SELECT ROUND(RAND() * (200-10) + 10) as rd, 200 as two, 10 as ten FROM dual' );
    $r = mysql_fetch_array( $r );
}
$end = microtime(1);

echo  ($end - $start) . " for MySQL select".PHP_EOL;

echo ':::::::::::::::::::::::::BEGINNING PHP RAND::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::' .PHP_EOL;
$start = microtime(1);
for( $i = 0; $i < 100000; $i++ )
{
    $r = mysql_query( 'SELECT 200 AS two, 10 AS tem FROM dual' );
    $r = mysql_fetch_array( $r );
    $r[2]= rand($r[0], $r[1]);
}
$end = microtime(1);

echo  ($end - $start) . " for PHP select".PHP_EOL;
```

MySQL comes out behind by 3-4% (very inconsistent results) (about the same results if you don't use an array index assignment for $r[2]).

The major difference, it seems, comes from the number of records return to PHP and not the randomization system itself. So, if you need column A, column B, and a random value, use PHP. If you only need the random value, then use MySQL.

Comment: Ok. I am surprised, because that is vice-versa of the kind of answer I expected to hear. Honestly, I think that MySQL will handle this **much** slower than PHP. Anyone mind commenting that? as a general practice, I always avoid any math in MySQL query.

Comment: Try both ways and measure it ;) There's never too early for premature optimization!

Comment: I could be wrong. I'll run some benchmarks and then we'll know.

Comment: This method has some issues: the first and the last values has twice less probabilities that other numbers. But everything depends on particular application needs.

Comment: @cwallenpoole, You are using static numbers, rather than column values. I bet using the actual column values would make the MySQL method much slower.

Comment: @Guy That is a very good point. Do you have a data set ready? Because I think that this type of stuff is great to know.

Comment: When one says "random number between a and b" they usually mean "all integers between those two numbers inclusively with the same probability". This answer gets that wrong, see @Karolis's answer for the correct solution.

Answer (score 48):

This method guarantees the same statistical probability for each value:

```
SELECT FLOOR((RAND() * (max-min+1))+min)
```

Comment: I need a random value between those two variables, not one or the other.

Comment: @Guy sorry. I was inattentive :) Updated!

Comment: This is the same option as offered by @Kyle. There is no point repeating the same answer.

Comment: @Guy If somebody is trying to help you it doesn't mean he is trying to repeat somebody's answer :) Not sure I saw @Kyle's answer when I was writing this post (because of undeleting??). In any case +1 to @Kyle for taking into account the math.

Comment: the same answer is even mentioned in my question, though using ROUND rather then FLOOR. Neither is good though. Function should randomly do either CEIL or FLOOR to work perfectly.

Comment: @Guy All of us gave you almost the same answer :) I just wanted to note that FLOOR method is much better from mathematical point of view. In any case your question has a an obvious answer, so you would not expect something different and unusual. Even if there were such a function like `RAND(min_v, max_v)`, this would not be much faster because the need of internal calculations would be very similar.

Comment: this was exactly what i need it :)

Answer (score 3):

in case minimum range is 1, you can simply

```
SELECT FLOOR((RAND() * max_range) + 1)
```

in case minimum range is 0, you can even more simply

```
SELECT FLOOR((RAND() * max_range))
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you do something like this?

```
SELECT id, (FLOOR( 1 + RAND( ) *60 )) AS timer
FROM users
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/984396/how-to-get-mysql-random-integer-range)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how many rows you have in the table(s), using rand() in a query or subquery can be extremely slow.

You can seriously improve the speed by first putting the random value in a variable and then just using that in your query.

For example on a table with over 4 million rows...

This took over 10 minutes:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `customers` `Customer`
WHERE
    `id` = (
        SELECT
            FLOOR((RAND() * (max(`CustomerRand`.`id`) - min(`CustomerRand`.`id`) + 1)) + min(`CustomerRand`.`id`)) `random_id`
        FROM
            `customers` `CustomerRand`
    );
```

While this took about 3 seconds on average:

```
SELECT
   FLOOR((RAND() * (max(`CustomerRand`.`id`) - min(`CustomerRand`.`id`) + 1)) + min(`CustomerRand`.`id`)) `random_id`
FROM `customers` `CustomerRand` INTO @rand_id;

SELECT * FROM `customers` WHERE `id` = @rand_id;
```

You might even be able to put this into a stored procedure then if it's something you would want to do or re-use often. The stored procedure could then be called from PHP or Python or wherever

Answer (score 0):

You can use order by rand

```
SELECT virtual.num
FROM (
         SELECT 1 AS num UNION
         SELECT 2 AS num UNION
         SELECT 3 AS num
     ) virtual
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a little subquery, without the need to do custom functions or other complex things:

```
SELECT (SELECT min_v UNION SELECT max_v ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) FROM myTable ...
```

Ps. I know that the question is a bit old, but it can help new users.