# UPDATE all records with a random number from a range

Tags: mysql, random

I want to fill a column with a randomly chosen number for each record. In my case I want the number to be in the range 1-3.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550155/mysql-get-a-random-value-between-two-values

Comment: You haven't tried `UPDATE` and `RAND()`?

Answer (score 146):

Try this:

```
UPDATE tableName SET columnName = FLOOR( 1 + RAND( ) *3 );
```

From the MySQL [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand) for `RAND`:

> Returns a random floating-point value v in the range 0 <= v < 1.0.

So in the above query, the largest value which could be generated by `1 + RAND()*3` would be `3.999999`, which when floored would give 3.  The smallest value would occur when `RAND()` returns 0, in which case this would give 1.

Comment: Will there be a new random value for each row, or will it use the same for them all?

Comment: @luckydonald It generates a new random number for each row.

Comment: What if I wanted to update another column conditionally based on the random value?
Is there a way using maybe `SET @myRandom = FLOOR(1+RAND()*3)` ?
I mean in one query of course.

Answer (score 17):

Use [RAND()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand) function. It returns a random floating-point value v in the range `0 <= v < 1.0`. To obtain a random integer R in the range `i <= R < j`, use the expression `FLOOR(i + RAND() * (j − i + 1))`. For example, to obtain a random integer in the range the range `1<= R < 3`, use the following statement:

```
UPDATE tableName
SET ColumnName= FLOOR(1 + rand() * 3);
```

**N.B :** [RAND()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand) produces random float values from 0 to 1.

Answer (score -2):

Do this

```
UPDATE tableName SET columnName = FLOOR(RAND( ) + RAND( ));
```