# Get random number between 65 to 122

Tags: mysql, sql, random

I want to get random number between 65 to 122.I am using this query

```
SELECT (FLOOR(65 + RAND() * 122));
```

after getting help from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14865632/mysql-update-with-random-number-between-1-3) but it is giving me numbers outside the range of 65-122.
Please help.Thanks

Comment: Because RAND can generate 1 * 122 + 65 = 187

Comment: Already we have solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14798640/creating-a-random-number-using-mysql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT (FLOOR(65 + RAND() * 57));
```

Rand provides a number between 0-1. Like 0,75.
So if you want to get a number betwen 65 and 122 then:

```
65 = 65+0*57
122 = 65+1*57
```

Answer (score 3):

I think what you want is

65 + FLOOR( RAND() * 57 )

a minimum of 65 PLUS random of 0-57, so at the high end, 65 + 57 = 122

Answer (score 1):

`RAND()` returns a random number between 0 and 1, hence `65 + RAND() * 122` is equal to minimum/maximum:

```
MIN: 65 + 0 * 122 = 65 + (0 * 122) = 65 + 0 = 65
MAX: 65 + 1 * 122 = 65 + (1 * 122) = 65 + 122 = 187
```

Hence what you actually want `57` instead of `122` as `122 - 65 =  57`.

Now the minimum/maximum is:

```
MIN: 65 + 0 * 57 = 65 + (0 * 57) = 65 + 0 = 65
MAX: 65 + 1 * 57 = 65 + (1 * 57) = 65 + 57 = 122
```

---

Alternately, here's a custom function you can use:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION RAND_BETWEEN(min FLOAT, max FLOAT) 
    RETURNS FLOAT
    BEGIN
        RETURN min + ((max - min) * RAND());
    END//

DELIMITER ;
```

Usage:

```
SELECT RAND_BETWEEN(60, 120)        # eg. 115.81029510498047
SELECT RAND_BETWEEN(0, 150)         # eg. 62.729270935058594
SELECT RAND_BETWEEN(10000, 10005)   # eg. 10004.9560546875
SELECT FLOOR( RAND_BETWEEN(5, 10) ) # eg. 6
```

Answer (score 1):

A typical way to write this is:

```
select 65 + FLOOR( RAND() * (122 - 65))
```

Writing it this way allows you to easily see the extreme values.

By the way, your question is a bit unclear as to whether 122 is included.  The formula would be slightly different depending on that.

Comment: +1 and this one should be the accepted anwser.. because this one explains the most simple calculation behind the lower and upper bound