# Populating all rows from a column in SQL from a random PHP integer

Tags: php, mysql, random

I have a SQL database with data however would like to populate a certain field in every row with a different random integer.

The code works to populate the field with one single random integer therefore my question is how do you loop for each row while assigning it a random integer.

Edit:
Populating it dependent on another field condition

PHP Code Snippet:

```
 $data = rand(intval(5000),intval(57000));
 echo $data;
 $sql = "UPDATE Test SET Projection = ".$data;
 mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
 echo "complete"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL UPDATE with random number between 1-3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14865632/mysql-update-with-random-number-between-1-3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're about to `update` table with random integer, use MySQL:

```
SELECT (FLOOR( 1 + RAND( ) * 100 )) -- returns random int in 1-100
```

your php code:

```
//$data = rand(intval(5000),intval(57000));
//echo $data;
$low = 5000 ; $high = 57000 ; $d = $high - $low ;
$sql = "UPDATE Test
        SET Projection = (FLOOR( $low +RAND()* $d ))
        WHERE DayColumn in ( 'Friday' , 'Saturday' , 'Sunday')
        ;" ;
mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
echo "complete"
```

If you want do some thing else based on this value, before updating or after, let me know to edit my answer.

Comment: The SQL is more suitable as its a one time operation I was looking to do. What does the FLOOR statement do exactly in this query?

Comment: @AlexJenkinson just read the manual at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_floor

Comment: converts random number (float or double) to int @AlexJenkinson

Comment: Is it possible to do this with a condition of another field needing a value to be true?

Comment: yes, much complex or heavier than you want! let me edit the code @AlexJenkinson `WHERE col1 = 'val1' AND col2 = 'val2'` added to code

Comment: @MohaMad So for example if column Day = Friday, Saturday, Sunday. It edits through a random integer?

Comment: Use `in` like this: `WHERE DayColumn in ( 'Friday' , 'Saturday' , 'Sunday')` if DayColumn is in this array, it would update table rows. and a question: DayColumn is string or `date` ?

Comment: @MohaMad why wouldn't you use an OR in this context? It is a string the date is another column itself.

Comment: `OR` needs more typing! and I don't know any performance differences between `OR` and `IN (..)` [read here for performance and use `IN (..)` :D](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/782915/mysql-or-vs-in-performance)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136994/discussion-between-alex-jenkinson-and-mohamad).

Answer (score 2):

You could use an update  too  eg:

```
Update Test set Projection =  FLOOR(1 +  RAND() * 57000 )
```

> To obtain a random integer R in the range i <= R < j,
>
> use the expression
>
> ```
>  FLOOR(i + RAND() * (j − i))
> ```

see  man  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand

Comment: That is exactly what I'm looking for. So why multiply the RAND by 10000?

Comment: or 57000  if need

Comment: Is that the maximum?

Comment: remove `AS UNSIGNED)` at the end of line. or add `CAST` before `Floor` @scaisEdge