# Add a random value to an existing column in mysql and return it

Tags: python, mysql, discord.py

I am getting a little more involved with mysql and wanted to add a value to an existing value in a column.

I have already written the function for this. Previously I used the following function, but of course this no longer works with mysql, if I have seen correctly:

```py
earnings = random.randrange(300)
```

My new function is therefore:

```py
await cur.execute("UPDATE economy SET wallet=wallet + ROUND (1 + rand() *300) WHERE user=%s", (ctx.author.id,))
```

This part also works. But I would like to get the generated value from my `ROUND (1 + rand() *300)` function and output it. Is this possible at all and if so: How?

About other functions or possibilities that show me a number at the end I would be grateful too!

Posts I have already looked at:

https://database.guide/mysql-rand-function-generate-a-random-number-in-mysql/

[creating a random number using MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14798640/creating-a-random-number-using-mysql)

[MySQL UPDATE with random number between 1-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14865632/mysql-update-with-random-number-between-1-3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this using a [user-defined variable](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html):

```
SET @r = ROUND(1 + RAND() * 300);

UPDATE economy SET wallet=wallet + @r WHERE user=%s;

SELECT @r;
```

I'll leave the Python code to execute these statements to you. Just use the same connection, and that will ensure that the user-defined variable will retain its value from one execute() call to the next.