# select 1 random number from mysql database using asp.net c#

Tags: mysql, random

How can i select 1 random number from database thats ID is autoincrement field.I have 25,000[ID]  records in database.Each every time select one new random ID.
How can get it.

Comment: Please elaborate your question.

Comment: In my database table ID[auto increment],product name  two fields then total product is extractly 30,000 records.Now 30,000 members are there and now each members show one PRODUCT randomly through ID without repeated ID. thats it.This information is enough for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following sql(slow)

```
'SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1'
```

or you can use(fast)

```
SELECT * FROM myTable, (SELECT FLOOR(MAX(myTable.id) * RAND()) AS randId FROM myTable) AS someRandId WHERE myTable.id = someRandId.randId
```

The inner SELECT gives you a random id in the right range.
The outer SELECT looks for the right row in the table.

Comment: Thanks for quick response@Ravi Kumar Mistry.I had already try that query ORDER BY RAND() makes  performance issue.Any other way..

Comment: i not runned the Query in the sql so it may be wrong, What i am trying to do in the last query is take 1 record and skip random number(less then total records) of record

Comment: code working fine.I try to upload 10 id after that  10 times  execute the query show the result 1,7,2,9,1,7,5,2,6,3.In the result 7 ,1,2 are repeated two times.I dont want repeat the same number

Comment: This is the nature of the Random no, no one knows what is next. To do that you need to handle it explicitly because after a query executes and return the data it don't know anything about the previous result set .So  handle it in your code .

Comment: you can maintain an int array in your code containing the last 100 id if new    record ID matches any of the id in array discard the result set and run the query again.[TIP: keep the array small larger the array most probable the record found in the array]

Comment: I had already tried that array list .some times shows repeat value.

Comment: What is your actual use case?

Comment: Do you mean asking my requirements.

Comment: yaah, to give better solution to your problem

Comment: online lucky draw system total 10000 users and 10000 different products..each user  onclick show 1 product that it

Comment: Add an extra  boolean column 'Shown' in database if product is shown mark that column true.  and write a query which filter all the not shown data and then apply this random select on that result set.

Comment: Accept it as answer if this is what you want

Comment: Thanks @  Ravi Kumar Mistry.I think your idea will working fine.

Comment: getting error,  select ID,productname, from  products  where  Pcount='" + strue + "',select RAND() as ID

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following [query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550155/mysql-get-a-random-value-between-two-values) to generate a random number between 0 and `COUNT`-1 of your table rows:

```
SELECT ROUND((RAND() * (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable)-1))
```

Then use this number as an *offset* in the `LIMIT` clause of your query to get a random row from your table.

Using a *prepared statement*, you can do:

```
SET @offset = (SELECT ROUND((RAND() * (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable)-1)));

PREPARE STMT FROM 'SELECT * FROM mytable LIMIT ?, 1';
EXECUTE STMT USING @offset;
```

Note that use of the prepared statement is mandatory since as documented in the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html):

> LIMIT takes one or two numeric arguments, which must both be
>   non-negative integer **constants** (*except when using prepared
>   statements*).

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/15495/2)

Comment: I was tried that query executes already generated value will show.how to overcome that repeating value