# UPDATE values from a table to another using rand() in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables and I need to `UPDATE` the value of `table1` for `uid = 0`.

Here my tables:

table1: *games*

```
id      | uid     | 
--------+---------+
1       | 5       | 
2       | 7       | 
3       | 0       |
```

table2: *users*

```
idu     | name    | 
--------+---------+
1       | todd    | 
2       | mario   | 
3       | luigi   |
```

So basically I need to `UPDATE` the `uid` value of the 3rd row of `table1` with a random number between 1-3 (`idu` values of `table2`).

For the purpose I tried this:

```
UPDATE games (uid)
SET idu = ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1 FROM users
WHERE uid = 0;
```

Why it's not working?

Comment: Actually, this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6550197/2737474

Comment: Not clear what would be the expected result after the update is done ?

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty I wrote" I need to UPDATE the uid value of the 3rd row of table1 with a random number between 1-3 (idu values of table2)."

Comment: @CharlesRojas thanks but I don't need to random 2 tables...`rand() LIMIT 1` should be correct

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty I need to update the `0` value of `uid` with a random `idu`...I don't know how to better explain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why can't you do like

```
UPDATE games SET uid = (
select idu from users ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1)
WHERE uid = 0;
```

Per your comment, in that case use a compound condition. So in your case use the `ID` column as well in condition like

```
WHERE uid = 0 AND ID = 3;
```

Which will make sure that only row with `ID = 3` getting updated considering the fact that your `ID` column is primary key / unique key column.

Comment: yes this is really nice...but is it possible to use it for `UPDATE` only the first row with `uid=0` and not all rows with `uid=0`?

Comment: Whichever row matches the condition `uid = 0` will be updated.

Comment: I wish to get a different random number for each `uid=0` . Any possible solution?

Answer (score 1):

I guess this might help you

```
SELECT @idu := idu FROM users ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
UPDATE games SET uid = @idu WHERE uid = 0;
```

However, this will update ALL rows where games.uid = 0 with the same randomly fetched users.idu

Comment: damn :) ...is there any possible solution to avoid it? I need to have diifferent random value for each cell that has 0 value