# LIMIT by random number between 1 and 10

Tags: mysql, random, sql-limit

Essentially, I want to return X number of records from the last 21 days, with an upper limit of 10 records.

How do I add a *random* `LIMIT` to a query in MySQL?

Here's my query, with `X` for the random number 1-10.

```
SELECT releases.id, COUNT(charts_extended.release_id) as cnt FROM releases
INNER JOIN charts_extended
ON charts_extended.release_id=releases.id
WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(), releases.date) < 21
GROUP BY releases.id
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 0, X
```

I tried using `RAND() * 10 + 1`, but it gives a syntax error.

Is there any way to do this using pure SQL; ie without using an application language to "build" the query as a string and have the application language fill in `X` programmatically?

Comment: Why would you want to do this (and LIMIT without ORDER BY is anyway meaningless)?

Comment: Would like to return a random number of results, with a max limit of 10

Comment: Is there any kind of application level code (e.g. PHP)?

Comment: There will be, designing the query first - i updated the question with the actual query if that helps?

Comment: Handle this problem there. Just make a for loop of a random size

Comment: already answered I think, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550155/mysql-get-a-random-value-between-two-values in my opinion get the rows from MySQL, randomize the presentation using PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eureka...

In pseudo code:

- execute a query to select 10 random rows
- select from that assigning a row number 0-9 using a user defined variable to calculate that
- cross join with a single hit on `rand()` to create a number 0-9 and select all rows with row number less than or equal to that number

Here's the essence of the solution (you can adapt your query to work with it:

```
select * from (
  select *, (@row := coalesce(@row + 1, 0)) row from (
    // your query here, except simply LIMIT 10
    select * from mytable
    order by rand()
    limit 10
  ) x
) y
cross join (select rand() * 10 rand) z
where row <= rand
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a12f41/5). Run it a few times and you'll see you get 1-10 random rows.

If you don't want to see the row number, you can change the outer `select *` to select only the specific columns from the inner query that you want in your result.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is correct but you need to update limit clause.

```
$query = "SELECT releases.id, COUNT(charts_extended.release_id) as cnt FROM releases
INNER JOIN charts_extended
ON charts_extended.release_id=releases.id
WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(), releases.date) < 21
GROUP BY releases.id
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 0,".rand(1,10);
```

and then execute this query.

Comment: This isn't actually what I need - I need to return a random number (between 1 and 10) of results

Comment: I have updated the answer, you need to pass the X variable in limit using PHP.