# choose a table randomly mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 identically structured tables called low, med, high. I would like to randomly choose one table from these tables, then query that table.

visual example:

`SELECT * FROM RAND(low,med,high)`

Comment: `I have 3 identically structured tables called low, med, high.` looks like you should rather have table with additional column for your low, med, high instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used the PHP tag, so in that language it can be like this:

```
$tables = ['low', 'med', 'high'];
$randomTable = $tables[mt_rand(0, 2)];
$query = 'SELECT * FROM '.$randomTable;

$mysqli = new mysqli("host","my_user","my_password","my_db");
$result = $mysqli -> query( $query);
```

In MySQL, in addition to the other solutions, it can be like this:

Select the table randomly:

```
set @randomNumber = FLOOR(RAND()*3+1);

set @table = IF(@randomNumber = 1, 'low', IF(@randomNumber = 2, 'med', 'high'));
```

or

```
set @table = CASE
    WHEN @randomNumber = 1 THEN 'low'
    WHEN @randomNumber = 2 THEN 'med'
    ELSE 'high'
END;
```

Build and run the query:

```
SET @s = CONCAT('select * from ', @table); 
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @s; 
EXECUTE stmt1; 
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
```

[How to select from MySQL where Table name is Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809943/how-to-select-from-mysql-where-table-name-is-variable)

[MySQL get a random value between two values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550155/mysql-get-a-random-value-between-two-values)

Comment: I chose this answer because the script is faster. Tim Biegeleisen's answer worked also. But I am trying to add additional queries using UNION and I must be missing something. Here is the code: $tables = ['low', 'med', 'high'];
$randomTable = $tables[mt_rand(0, 2)]; 
$query2 = ' 
(SELECT * FROM low ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,3) 
UNION
(SELECT * FROM med ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1) 
UNION
(SELECT * FROM '.$randomTable.' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1)

';

Comment: Thank you. Please, can you explain what you expect from that query? And what is wrong with it? Does it throw an error, or an unwanted result?

Comment: The code above works but I added some WHERE clauses that caused a syntax error. I found the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may use a union approach which assigns a computed value of 1, 2, or 3, to each of the three tables, then randomly choose the records from just one table:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *, 1 AS label FROM low UNION ALL
    SELECT *, 2 FROM med UNION ALL
    SELECT *, 3 FROM high
) t
WHERE label = FLOOR(RAND()*3+1);  -- random number between 1 and 3 inclusive
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from high
union all
select * from med
union all
select * from low
order by rand()
limit 1
```

#### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2b7a31/3)