# Insert random number with mysql

Tags: php, mysql, insert

i have a question in regards to mysql mainly. i have the following:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO {$game}_ships (location,login_id
         ) values(
    '250','44')");
```

i would like to make the location a random number from 2 to 300.

my table structure includes among others a column for location and login id, i dont need to mention other columns as they are static and do not change.
the above is suposed to make a ship look like its moving around the systems.

```
location   int(4)
```

can anyone help with this?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/984396/how-to-get-mysql-random-integer-range - `(FLOOR( 2 + RAND( ) * 300 ))`

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL get a random value between two values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550155/mysql-get-a-random-value-between-two-values)

Comment: This will generate a number between 2 and 302. You have to subtract the min from max on the multiplication, like I've posted in my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO {$game}_ships (location,login_id
         ) values(
    FLOOR(RAND() * 298 + 2),'44')");
```

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand

Comment: the above is giving me a 0 location.

Comment: There might be something wrong with your column datatype then. Could you edit you question to show us table structure?

Comment: i have updated the question and tested it again. the result is 0. i have a problem with location 0, it does not exist. lol

Comment: The actual datatype of this column is what is of onterest here. Do `SHOW CREATE TABLE yourTableName` and paste the row where it describes `location` column

Comment: In such case, double check if you copied my answer correctly. Don't add any quotes to it (you have quotes around `250` in your original query - they are not needed. If you copied it exactly, and it still inserts 0, then some magick is going on, and I've no idea what kind.

Comment: lol, removed the quotes and it worked. bingo. lol, thank you very much. :)

Comment: For the record. you don't need quotes around `44` either (assuming `login_id` is also an `int()`

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME(rand_col) VALUES(FLOOR($MIN_VAL + (RAND() * ($MAX_VAL - $MIN_VAL))));
```

Where `MIN_VAL` is your lower number (2) and `MAX_VAL` is your higher number(300)

Comment: its not a random column, im trying to randomize an insert to make it look like a ship is moving around.

Comment: My example does exactly this. It's an insert and the MIN_VAL and MAX_VAL are only placeholders: `mysql_query("INSERT INTO {$game}_ships (location,login_id 
         ) values( 
    FLOOR(2 + (RAND() * (300 - 2))),'44')");` That does the same as your acepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use PHP's rand instead?

```
mt_rand(2,300)
```

Comment: my guess both answers the random didnt work because i still get a 0 system.

Comment: Can you output the result of mt_rand to make sure it is working?

Comment: mt_rand works but its not inserting a valid integer in the database and its reverting back to default, which is 0.

Comment: according to your original query (at least) you'd be trying to insert a string into an integer type? Lose the quotes and maybe that will fix it.