# Retrieve an arbitrary number of random rows from each 'group by' category in MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, random, group-by

I have a table in MySQL that contains a column name `category`.
I am trying to write a query that will return 2 random records from each `category`.

Here is code that I use to get 2 records from each `category` with the highest values in my `rating` column:

```
SELECT e1.* 
FROM   entries AS e1 
WHERE  (SELECT Count(*) 
        FROM   entries AS e2 
        WHERE  e2.category = e1.category 
               AND e1.rating <= e2.rating) <= 2 
ORDER  BY category, 
          rating DESC
```

Check this link out to see a table with some sample data and the above query:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bab8e/1

Comment: what exactly you require..2 random records from each category right?? or something, does that related to query you have included..!?

Comment: The query is just there to show what I'm working with, say that I have 30 entries in a table 10 of each category, I would like to retrieve 2 random entries of each of those categories. That would return 6 results.

Comment: Take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/984396/how-to-get-mysql-random-integer-range

Answer (score 1):

I achieved your desired results by sorting the table by the category column and a random number. I then assigned an incrementing number to each row that starts over each at 1 each time the category changed. I then return only the results that have a rowNum that is less than or equal to 2. If you wanted to return 3 random rows you would just change it to less than or equal to 3 and so on.

```
SELECT entry_id, 
       category, 
       rating 
FROM   (SELECT @currank := IF(@category = category, @currank + 1, 1) AS rowNum, 
               @category := category                                 AS categoryVar, 
               e1.* 
        FROM   (SELECT *, 
                       (SELECT @currank := 0) r 
                FROM   entries 
                ORDER  BY category, 
                          Rand()) AS e1)AS e2 
WHERE  rownum <= 2 
ORDER  BY category, 
          rating;
```

Here is an sqlfiddle link like the one you posted in your question:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bab8e/37/0

---

Do note that this same query could easily be adjusted to return a set number of records that are not random. For example, if you wanted to return the top 5 `rating`s from each `category` you could change the

`ORDER BY category,rand()`

to

`ORDER BY category, rating DESC`

and changing

`WHERE  rownum <= 2`
to

`WHERE  rownum <= 5`