# How to use SQL's RAND() to generate 400, 450 or 500?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to use SQL's `RAND()`-function to get the number 400, 450 or 500 and insert it in a field inside a tabe.

How could I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get mysql random integer range?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/984396/how-to-get-mysql-random-integer-range)

Comment: I don't want a result of 401 or 498 or 432...
There is only 3 possibles values (400 OR 450 OR 500)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can follow code bellow

```
a = floor(rand() * 3);
value = 400 + a*50;
```

Answer (score 1):

First genterate ints from set [0,1,2] then multiple to 50 to get step in 50 then add seed

```
select floor(rand() * 3)  * 50 + 400
```